# Create custom copy button

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey am new to javascript but putting my all efforts I have written a javascript to showcase some quotes with dynamic pagination. Firstly please observe my javascript, html and css clearly. If you can just once run the code.

***My Javascript***

```
const resultEl = document.querySelector('.allquotes');
const pageSize = document.querySelector('select[name="page-size"]');
const pageCurr = document.querySelector('input[name="page-curr"]')
const resultCount = document.querySelector('.result-count')
const pageNoCurr = document.querySelector('.page-no-curr');
const pageNoCount = document.querySelector('.page-no-count')
const btnFirst = document.querySelector('.page-btn-first');
const btnPrev = document.querySelector('.page-btn-prev');
const btnNext = document.querySelector('.page-btn-next');
const btnLast = document.querySelector('.page-btn-last');

let results = [];

const getResultCount = () => results.length;
const getPageSize = () => +pageSize.value;
const getCurrPage = () => +pageCurr.value;
const getPageCount = () => Math.ceil(getResultCount() / getPageSize());

const pageResponse = (records, pageSize, page) =>
  (start => records.slice(start, Math.min(records.length, start + pageSize)))
  (pageSize * (page - 1));

const main = async() => {
  btnFirst.addEventListener('click', navFirst);
  btnPrev.addEventListener('click', navPrev);
  btnNext.addEventListener('click', navNext);
  btnLast.addEventListener('click', navLast);
  pageSize.addEventListener('change', changeCount);

  results = await retrieveAllQuotes();
  updatePager(results);
  redraw();
};
const redraw = () => {
  resultEl.innerHTML = '';
  const paged = pageResponse(results, getPageSize(), getCurrPage());
  const contents = document.createElement('div');
  contents.innerHTML = paged.map(record => `<div class='latestatus'><p class='copytxt'>${record.quotes}</p><div> <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button></div></div>`).join('');
  resultEl.append(contents);
};

const navFirst = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = 1;
  pageCurr.value = 1;
  redraw();
}

const navPrev = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const prevPage = curr > 1 ? curr - 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = prevPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = prevPage;
  redraw();
}

const navNext = (e) => {
  const pages = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  const nextPage = curr < pages ? curr + 1 : curr;
  pageCurr.value = nextPage;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = nextPage;
  redraw();
}

const navLast = (e) => {
  pageNoCurr.textContent = getPageCount();
  pageCurr.value = getPageCount();
  redraw();
}

const changeCount = () => {
  updatePager();
  redraw();
};

const updatePager = () => {
  const count = getPageCount();
  const curr = getCurrPage();
  pageCurr.value = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCurr.textContent = curr > count ? 1 : curr;
  pageNoCount.textContent = count;
  resultCount.textContent = getResultCount();
};

const retrieveAllQuotes = async function() {

  // write your asynchronous fetching here

  return[{
      quotes: "1The cat is better than dog."
    },
    {
      quotes: "2Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "3Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "4Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "5Life is short make it possible."
    },
    {
      quotes: "6The cat is better than dog"
    },
    {
      quotes: "7Google is a open source library."
    },
    {
      quotes: "8Cats are better than ferrets."
    },
    {
      quotes: "9Love books."
    },
    {
      quotes: "10Life is short make it possible."
    },
]; 
main();
```

***My Html***

```
 <div class="allquotes"></div>
<div class="pagable-status">
  <label>Page <span class="page-no-curr">1</span> of <span class="page-no-count">1</span></label>
  <div class="pagable-actions">
    <button class="page-btn-first">&#x226A;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-prev">&#60;</button>
    <input type="number" name="page-curr" min="1" value="1" />
    <button class="page-btn-next">&#62;</button>
    <button class="page-btn-last">&#x226B;</button>
    <select name="page-size">
      <option>5</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>20</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <label>(<span class="result-count"></span> items)</label>
</div>
```

***My CSS***

```
display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: var(--pageable-border);
  background: var(--pageable-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-status {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--pageable-status-background);
}

.pagable .pagable-actions {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.pagable .pagable-actions input[name="page-curr"] {
  width: 3em;
}
.mainStatus{
 background-color: #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 max-width: 95%;
 width: 95%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 20px;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.statusHeading{
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 border-top-left-radius: 20px;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.latestatus{
 display: grid;
 height: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
 width: 445px;
 min-height: 130px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.copystatus{
 font-weight: 500;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
}
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: var(--primary-color);
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 30px;
}
:root {
  --primary-color: linear-gradient(#18b495, #16a085);
}
```

Now let's talk about my query. I wanted the button `<button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>` to copy the respective quote when it is clicked. I have tried it by some code but its not working.
My code for reference

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('copystatus');
for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     let statusElement = this.closest('.latestatus');
     let textToCopy = statusElement.getElementsByClassName('copytxt')[0].innerHTML;
    
    copyTextToClipboard(textToCopy);
    addCopyStatusAlert(this.parentNode);
  });
}
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  const copyText = document.createElement('textarea');
  copyText.style.position="absolute";
  copyText.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(copyText);
}

function addCopyStatusAlert(element) {
  if (!element.getElementsByClassName('status-copy-alert').length) {
    let copyAlertElement = document.createElement('span');
    copyAlertElement.classList.add('status-copy-alert')
    let copyMessage = document.createTextNode('Copied!');
    copyAlertElement.appendChild(copyMessage);
      element.appendChild(copyAlertElement);
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.removeChild(copyAlertElement);
    }, 700);
  }
}
```

Please help me to make this code so dynamic that the pagination and copy command both should work perfectly.

I thank in advance for those who answer this question.

Comment: your html doesnt contains any button with copystatus class

Comment: I have created it from javascript. Please read my javascript first.

Comment: Dual post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65804598/creat-copy-button-for-json-data